# Did Luke Skywalker kill any innocents when he was Darth Sidious' apprentice?

Tags: star-wars

In the EU, Luke becomes the reborn Sidious' apprentice. During this time did he kill any Jedi or innocents, like Anakin did, to fully turn to the dark side?

From Wookieepedia:

> It was then that the resurrected Emperor struck. Using his dark powers
>   to create a powerful Force storm, he swept Luke Skywalker to Byss.
>   There, he revealed himself to Luke, and revealed the power of the dark
>   side. Faced with an immortal foe, Skywalker did the unthinkable — in
>   order to defeat the dark side from within, he knelt before Sidious,
>   and submitted himself as the Emperor's new Sith apprentice

Comment: That's part of a comic series called Dark Empire.  I haven't read the comic series myself just from a quick glance of the wiki it seems that Luke just pretended to submit himself, I don't think he actually killed any innocents or Jedis.

Comment: Since when do you have to kill Jedi or innocents to 'fully turn to the Dark Side'?  Hell, the Emperor said, "Strike me down and your journey towards the Dark Side of the Force will be complete" in ROTJ, and Palpatine is about as far from 'innocent' as you can get.

Comment: Its just that annakin didnt get his shiny new eyes till after he decimated the jedi Temple and wiped out the seperatists

Comment: @Jeff well it would be a good test to see if someone was evil or not. "Luke, kill those babies!"... "No Sidious,, I won't do it!"... "Ah Luke, I knew you were faking. Ya big faker!".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've had a look through the [*Dark Empire*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Empire) series of comics and I'm pleased to confirm that Luke doesn't really do anything especially evil after he (sort of) turns to the Dark side.

After evidently submitting to the newly reborn Palpatine, he smacks Leia and Han about a bit. He steals the command codes for Palpie's fleet, smacks Leia about a bit (again) then turns back to the Light Side of the Force with Leia's help and together they kill the Palpatine clone.

[image]
[image]

then later...
[image]

Comment: Even street gangs know you gotta make the recruit do something immoral to cement him into the group.

Comment: @Oldcat - True. I'd at least have had him kill an ewok or something...

Comment: @Richard - Yub-yub

Comment: I've always thought that the Emperor could hold the galaxy to ransom by threatening to clone Jarjar a few thousand times.

Comment: @Richard - that's a little TOO immoral, even for Palpatine.

Comment: @Richard 35 Ewoks or 1 Wookie.

Comment: @Richard: How is killing Ewoks evil?  Seriously, more of them need to die.  Wait...am I evil?

Comment: @Jeff No. I know of two other SF races that resemble teddy bears, and they're both murderous.